How can I use clip-path or skew css to give diagonal cuts to the images and make it similar to the example image and avoid those white spaces and join
How can I avoid those white spaces in my cuts using clip-path or can I do it with CSS skew or how could I make the design similar to how it is in the image with the images together next to each other, could you help me and tell me how do i do it

my css code is this:
.cont__imagenes{
display: flex;
}

.img__{
height: 500px;
width: 350px;
object-fit: cover;
}

.corte_inicial{
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 55% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.corte_diagonal{
clip-path: polygon(55% 0, 100% 0, 50% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.corte_final{
clip-path: polygon(55% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}```
    
my html code is this:

    <div class="cont__imagenes">
        <div class="subcont__imagenes">
             <img class="img__ corte_inicial" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?winter,night" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="subcont__imagenes">
               <img class="img__ corte_diagonal" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?space,night" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="subcont__imagenes">
             <img class="img__ corte_diagonal" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?winter" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="subcont__imagenes">
              <img class="img__ corte_diagonal" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/900×700/?space" alt="personas">
        </div>
        <div class="subcont__imagenes">
             <img class="img__ corte_final" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?montain" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    


Not the obvious problem as stated in the question, but another one: why 55%? This leads to each ‘slice’ not having parallel sides, so whatever we do the images will have some space between.

If you want the images right next to each other you have to create an overlap of 50% between them (and the polygon has to be to 50% not 55% otherwise you get non-parallel sides):


.cont__imagenes {
  display: flex;
}

.img__ {
  height: 500px;
  width: 350px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.corte_inicial {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 50% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.corte_diagonal {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 0, 50% 100%, 0 100%);
  rtransform: translateX(-50%);
  margin-left: -175px;
}

.corte_final {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  margin-left: -175px;
}
<div class="cont__imagenes">
  <div class="subcont__imagenes">
    <img class="img__ corte_inicial" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?winter,night" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="subcont__imagenes">
    <img class="img__ corte_diagonal" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?space,night" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="subcont__imagenes">
    <img class="img__ corte_diagonal" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?winter" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="subcont__imagenes">
    <img class="img__ corte_diagonal" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/900×700/?space" alt="personas">
  </div>
  <div class="subcont__imagenes">
    <img class="img__ corte_final" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?montain" alt="">
  </div>
</div>



If you want borders between them then don't move them quite so much and have a background which will show through:


.cont__imagenes {
  display: flex;
}

.img__ {
  height: 500px;
  width: 350px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.corte_inicial {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 50% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.corte_diagonal {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 0, 50% 100%, 0 100%);
  margin-left: -170px;
}

.corte_final {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  margin-left: -170px;
}
<div class="cont__imagenes">
  <div class="subcont__imagenes">
    <img class="img__ corte_inicial" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?winter,night" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="subcont__imagenes">
    <img class="img__ corte_diagonal" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?space,night" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="subcont__imagenes">
    <img class="img__ corte_diagonal" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?winter" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="subcont__imagenes">
    <img class="img__ corte_diagonal" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/900×700/?space" alt="personas">
  </div>
  <div class="subcont__imagenes">
    <img class="img__ corte_final" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?montain" alt="">
  </div>
</div>




Thanks for the answer, testing I realized that I could move it with translatex() but thanks for the suggestion, thanks too
